# Using tokens in PicketLink with LDAP-based identity store in Java EE 7 (WildFly)

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jwt, picketlink

I'm trying to secure RESTful web services with JWT tokens; it's basically [picketlink-angularjs-rest: PicketLink AngularJS and REST Security](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-angularjs-rest) quickstart but with LDAP (AD) identity store.

When client tries to acquire a token LDAP authorization works fine, but then `NullPointerException` occurs when JWSTokenProvider [attempts to update the account with the token](https://github.com/pedroigor/picketlink-quickstarts/blob/master/picketlink-angularjs-rest/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/picketlink/angularjs/security/authentication/JWSTokenProvider.java#L73).

```java
14:18:51,463 ERROR [org.picketlink.http] (default task-1) Exception thrown during processing for path [/web/rest/authenticate]. Sending error with status code [500].: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: PLIDM000201: Credential update failed for account [org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User@bd0f05c0] and type [app.security.jws.JWSToken@7abd2a33].
    (...)
    at org.picketlink.http.internal.authentication.schemes.TokenAuthenticationScheme.issueToken(TokenAuthenticationScheme.java:222) [picketlink-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.http.internal.authentication.schemes.TokenAuthenticationScheme.onPostAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationScheme.java:128) [picketlink-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.performAuthenticationIfRequired(SecurityFilter.java:437) [picketlink-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.http.internal.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:174) [picketlink-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    (...)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManagementException: PLIDM000201: Credential update failed for account [org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User@bd0f05c0] and type [app.security.jws.JWSToken@7abd2a33].
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:235) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:217) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at app.security.jws.JWSTokenProvider.issue(JWSTokenProvider.java:50) [app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    (...)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.DefaultStoreSelector.getStoreForCredentialOperation(DefaultStoreSelector.java:221) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.idm.internal.ContextualIdentityManager.updateCredential(ContextualIdentityManager.java:231) [picketlink-idm-impl-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    ... 112 more
```

(full stacktrace is [here](https://gist.github.com/jarek-przygodzki/6f284c3224f537535a90))

How can I make this scenario work? Or if it's impossible in PicketLink, what's the alternative?" I'm using  Java EE 7 and WildFly application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this configuration is not supported? Check Picketlink documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/sect-Built-in_Credential_Handlers.html

`org.picketlink.idm.credential.TokenCredential` Used for Token-based authentication is supported by `JPAIdentityStore` and `FileBasedIdentityStore`